# What OAuth flow should I be using to get chat messages?

Tags: c#, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a Daemon Application, I've set the right application permissions on azure portal and
I'm trying to get the chat messages using /user/{id}/chats/{id}/messages/{id} with ClientCrediantialsFlow
the problem is, I get an Internal Error while doing so. when I try to get the user only, I get everything but that Chats are null.
Am I using wrong OAuth flow?
I need to be able to get any user's message by a chat id (which i get with subscription to /chats/allMessages).

This is how i create my GraphServiceClient:

```
        private GraphServiceClient GetGraphClientAsync()
        {
            string[] graphScopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId))
            .WithClientSecret(secret)
            .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
            return graphClient;
        }
```

another update:
I used postman with OAuth 2.0 ClientCredentials (using Microsoft Graph Postman Collection) to get a token and then tried to get the message with the token, again got 403 forbidden.

Comment: Have you granted application permissions to the application and granted administrator consent?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using wrong OAuth flow and client credentials flow will work.

OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow will only work for application permissions, and ChatMessages in  MS Graph Supports using Application permissions based on [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) you have shared.

Please go through [.net sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp) using client credentials flow which help you to implement your solution easily.

Comment: I'm confused, I'm not trying top get a "chat" but a "chatMessage"
as stated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
application permissions are supposed to work.

Comment: Hi @ArikShapiro,  Thank you for the update.we have updated our answer. Please let us know if anything required .

Comment: Thanks for the example! Is there an example maybe with the SDK using GraphServiceClient and ClientCrediantialProvider? I've updated my question with the code I have to make a GraphServiceClient

Comment: Also updating that with the example I got a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Hi @ArikShapiro, Based on [Ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors) you are facing problem with permissions. Make sure you have granted Admin consent because  application permissions require admin consent.Also, please go through [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS) which uses GraphServiceClient.Also go through more simplified [code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph/daemon-console) sample.

Comment: Hi, I have granted admin consent for chat.Read.All
It says "Granted for..." In azure portal.
I'll go through the document you've shared.

Comment: I've used https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/JwtDecoder/GetToken on the token I'm getting, It seems I am getting Chat.Read.All in the PayLoad so the token is fine.

Comment: @ArikShapiro,Are you still facing any issue after getting token?

Comment: I  was able to fix the issue, the problem was I didn't notice it's a Protected API.
after sending a request to microsoft, I was able to get access to the Protected API and was able to pull messages.
thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You must grant application permissions to your application and grant **administrator consent**.

code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var chat = await graphClient.Users["{id}"].Chats["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```